# cs50 scrabble game: always prints same answer, no matter what typed in

Tags: c, cs50, scrabble

i need to program a scrabble game for the cs50 course. right now i have this code but the problem is at first it always printed "Tie!" and now it always prints out "Player 2 wins!" no matter what i type in. i think my mistake is in for loop where u assign the letters to the number but i dont really know how i can fix it. does anyone may have an idea how?

```
// Points assigned to each letter of the alphabet
int POINTS[] = {1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 8, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 8, 4, 10};

int compute_score(string word1);
int compute_scores(string word2);

int main(void)
{
    // Get input words from both players
    string word1 = get_string("Player 1: ");
    string word2 = get_string("Player 2: ");

    // Score both words
    int score1 = (int) compute_score;
    int score2 = (int) compute_scores;

    // Print the winner
    if (score1 == score2)
    {
        printf("Tie! \n");
    }
    if (score1 < score2)
    {
        printf("Player 2 wins! \n");
    }
    if (score1 > score2)
    {
        printf("Player 1 wins! \n");
    }
}

int compute_score(string word1)
{
    // Compute and return score for string
    int compute_score = 0;
    int numb;
    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(word1); i < n; i++)
    {
        if(isupper(word1[i]))
        {
            numb = word1[i] - 65;
            numb = POINTS[numb];
        }
        if(islower(word1[i]))
        {
            numb = word1[i] - 97;
            numb = POINTS[numb];
        }
        else
        {
             numb = 0;
        }
    }
    compute_score = numb;
    return compute_score;
}

int compute_scores(string word2)
{
    // Compute and return score for string
    int compute_scores = 0;
    int numb;
    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(word2); i < n; i++)
    {
        if(isupper(word2[i]))
        {
            numb = word2[i] - 65;
            numb = POINTS[numb];
        }
        if(islower(word2[i]))
        {
            numb = word2[i] - 97;
            numb = POINTS[numb];
        }
        else
        {
            numb = 0;
        }
    }
    compute_scores = numb;
    return compute_scores;
}
```

Comment: Why do you have two identical functions?

Comment: `int score1 = (int) compute_score;` this isn't calling the function, it's taking its address in memory as a number. Try `int score1 = compute_score(word1);`

Comment: Why did you add `(int)` in `int score1 = (int) compute_score;`?

Comment: @4386427 Yep, and why on earth would you do something like that? :)

Comment: I'm curious about what made OP think that's a good idea

Comment: @4386427 if i do it like this it always prints "Tie!" thats why i changed it but that didnt really helped cause then it always printed "Player 2 wins!".

Comment: Now that it will be actually calling those functions, time to bust out the debugger, step through the code and observe the values of the variables. (`numb` may be a good start)

Comment: You need to study the basics more. Just guessing will not do you any good and your attempt to make a function call makes no sense at all.

Comment: And having two completely identical functions is probably the most pointless thing that can be done. It completely defeats the purpose of functions, which is to reuse code so that you don't have to have the same code twice.

Comment: my input is a word the user writes and then i want the program to give me the points for each letter and at the end adds those and gives them back as compute_score(word1) and compute_score(word2).

Comment: @klutt but how can i add them together that they use both words and then gives them back as individual so i can use them?

Answer (score 1):

When you are a beginner, there exists almost no situation where you need to use a cast, ever. Or in the rare case where you need one, you need to know what you are doing.

`int score1 = (int) compute_score;` converts the unsigned address of the function itself to a signed int where it might not fit. That's nonsense. You need to *call* the function and store the result in an `int`. No casting anywhere.

I'd recommend reading about functions in your favourite C book. I also recommend dropping CS-50 since it's a bad class teaching bad practices. It has a poor reputation among C programmers.

Comment: which C book would u recommend?

Answer (score 1):

This

```
int score1 = (int) compute_score;
int score2 = (int) compute_scores;
```

is **not** how you do function calls in C. What you want is this:

```
int score1 = compute_score(word1);
int score2 = compute_scores(word2);
```

But wait... It seems the functions `compute_score` and `compute_scores` are identical. If so... you don't need two functions. Simply use the same function for both calculations

```
int score1 = compute_score(word1);
int score2 = compute_score(word2);
```

and delete the other function.

However, your current function seems wrong...

```
int compute_score(string word1)
{
    // Compute and return score for string
    int compute_score = 0;
    int numb;

    // Why do you have a loop here?
    // Inside the loop you keep overwriting numb so it is
    // only the last iteration that matters.
    // In other words... the result only depends on the
    // last character in the string.
    // Did you intend to do something like:
    //    numb = numb + ....
    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(word1); i < n; i++)
    {
        if(isupper(word1[i]))
        {
            numb = word1[i] - 65;
            numb = POINTS[numb];
        }
        if(islower(word1[i]))   <----- Missing else ??
        {
            numb = word1[i] - 97;
            numb = POINTS[numb];
        }
        else
        {
             numb = 0;
        }
    }
    compute_score = numb;  \
    return compute_score;   \---> These lines can simply be: return numb;
}
```

Maybe this is what you want:

```
int compute_score(string word)
{
    // Compute and return score for string
    int numb = 0;

    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(word); i < n; i++)
    {
        if(isupper(word[i]))
        {
            numb += POINTS[word[i] - 'A'];
        }
        else if(islower(word[i]))
        {
            numb += POINTS[word[i] - 'a'];
        }
    }
    return numb;
}
```